# How to enable SPDY in LiteSpeed?

Tags: spdy, litespeed

I have the latest LiteSpeed Enterprise running on my server. It was not installed with SPDY enabled.

**How do I enable SPDY?**

*The server got lots of IPs and SSL certificates.*

*I've seen that it might be possible by recompiling LiteSpeed but that's nothing I feel like doing as a heavy Windows user.*

*The server got WHM/cPanel installed as well.*

Comment: A quick google and I read a comment that SPDY will be available in LightSpeed 5. That's currently listed as a release candidate on the webpage.  So you probably running version 4 which doesn't support SPDY yet.

Comment: I see. What did you google to find the information?

Comment: I just googled "LightSpeed SPDY"

Comment: http://www.litespeedtech.com/support/forum/threads/googles-spdy.4898/#post-75303

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As noted in the comments, SPDY is only available in LSWS Enterprise 5.0 (and OpenLiteSpeed). Version 5.0 is currently on RC1 (and soon to be RC2), so it's not really recommended for use on production machines.

To enable SPDY on LSWS Enterprise 5.0, go to the WebAdmin console > Listeners > your listener > SSL > Enable SPDY. Then just check the version(s) of SPDY you want enabled.

m